# AIDL and Messenger at the same time

Tags: android, aidl, messenger

I try to write a demo about how to use the AIDL and the Messenger at the same time, but I have an error, and I don't know the reason.

MessengerDEMOActivity.java

```
public class MessengerDEMOActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private MessengerDEMOServiceConnection MDSconnection = null;
    private Messenger mMessenger = null;

    class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Bundle b = msg.getData();
            System.out.println("MESSENGER! " + b.getString("MESSENGER"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());

        MDSconnection = new MessengerDEMOServiceConnection(mMessenger);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("ID", "AIDL");
        intent.setClassName("messenger.demo", messenger.demo.MessengerDEMOService.class.getName());
        bindService(intent, MDSconnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    }
}
```

MessengerDEMOServiceConnection.java

```
public class MessengerDEMOServiceConnection implements ServiceConnection {

    private IMessengerDEMOService service = null;
    private Messenger mMessenger = null;

    public MessengerDEMOServiceConnection(Messenger mMessenger) {
        super();
        System.out.println("MessengerDEMOServiceConnection SocketServiceConnection()");
        this.mMessenger = mMessenger;
    }

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder boundService) {
        System.out.println("MessengerDEMOServiceConnection onServiceConnected()");
        service = IMessengerDEMOService.Stub.asInterface((IBinder) boundService);

        Messenger mService = new Messenger(boundService);

        Message msg = Message.obtain(null, 5);
        msg.replyTo = mMessenger;
        try {
            mService.send(msg); // line 31
        } catch (RemoteException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            service.foo();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        System.out.println("MessengerDEMOServiceConnection onServiceDisconnected()");
        service = null;
    }
}
```

MessengerDEMOService.java

```
public class MessengerDEMOService extends Service {

    private Messenger mMessenger = null;

    class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            System.out.println("MessengerDEMOService IncomingHandler");
            Messenger activityMessenger = msg.replyTo;
            Message m = new Message();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("MESSENGER", "blablabla");
            m.setData(b);
            try {
                activityMessenger.send(m);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        System.out.println("MessengerDEMOService onCreate");
        mMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        System.out.println("MessengerDEMOService onBind()");

        if (intent.getExtras().getString("ID").equals("AIDL") == true) {
            System.out.println("MessengerDEMOService onBind() AIDL");
            return new IMessengerDEMOService.Stub() {
                public void foo() {
                    System.out.println("MessengerDEMOService onBind() foo()");
                }
            };
        }

        System.out.println("MessengerDEMOService onBind() MESSENGER");
        return mMessenger.getBinder();
    }
}
```

And the stack trace:

```
12-27 16:42:29.412: INFO/System.out(832): MessengerDEMOServiceConnection SocketServiceConnection()
12-27 16:42:29.442: INFO/System.out(832): MessengerDEMOService onCreate
12-27 16:42:29.452: INFO/System.out(832): MessengerDEMOService onBind()
12-27 16:42:29.452: INFO/System.out(832): MessengerDEMOService onBind() AIDL
12-27 16:42:29.542: INFO/System.out(832): MessengerDEMOServiceConnection onServiceConnected()
12-27 16:42:29.572: WARN/Parcel(832): **** enforceInterface() expected 'messenger.demo.IMessengerDEMOService' but read 'android.os.IMessenger'
12-27 16:42:29.572: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(832): Shutting down VM
12-27 16:42:29.572: WARN/dalvikvm(832): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
12-27 16:42:29.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(832): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-27 16:42:29.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(832): java.lang.SecurityException: Binder invocation to an incorrect interface
12-27 16:42:29.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(832):     at android.os.Parcel.enforceInterface(Native Method)
12-27 16:42:29.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(832):     at messenger.demo.IMessengerDEMOService$Stub.onTransact(IMessengerDEMOService.java:49)
12-27 16:42:29.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(832):     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:249)
12-27 16:42:29.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(832):     at android.os.IMessenger$Stub$Proxy.send(IMessenger.java:89)
12-27 16:42:29.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(832):     at android.os.Messenger.send(Messenger.java:50)
12-27 16:42:29.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(832):     at messenger.demo.MessengerDEMOServiceConnection.onServiceConnected(MessengerDEMOServiceConnection.java:31)
12-27 16:42:29.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(832):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(ActivityThread.java:1247)
12-27 16:42:29.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(832):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(ActivityThread.java:1264)
12-27 16:42:29.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(832):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-27 16:42:29.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(832):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-27 16:42:29.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(832):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-27 16:42:29.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(832):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-27 16:42:29.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(832):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-27 16:42:29.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(832):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-27 16:42:29.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(832):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-27 16:42:29.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(832):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-27 16:42:29.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(832):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Without these lines the code is working:

```
Message msg = Message.obtain(null, 5);
            msg.replyTo = mMessenger;
            try {
                mService.send(msg); // line 31
            } catch (RemoteException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

It works without the AIDL and works the AIDL "alone". Can I call the onBinder more than one time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I call the onBinder more than one time?

**Simple answer**: yes. Actually this does happen if two different applications connect to the same service.

**So why doesn't this work**? Because you're using two different interfaces for communication.

**What happens in detail**:

1. You connect to the service (AIDL)
2. You try to `send` a message by the messenger
3. Android sends this message to the service by AIDL
4. First thing to do is, that the given interfaces do match (by comparing an `Interface Descriptor`) (See you `Stub.onTransact` for details)
5. Android notices that these interfaces do not match and throws a `SecurityException`

There is no `RemoteException` thrown because the `send()` method isn't invoked yet.

**Easy fix**: catch the `SecurityException`. But I'd consider this **extremly** bad style (as always it is when your application logic relays on exceptions).

**Not so easy fix**: 
For this to work, both interfaces would need to have to same interface descriptor (defined in `Stub.DESCRIPTOR` in your generated AIDL class). However you'd need to implement the Proxy/Stub for IPC by yourself (not that bad).

**Another fix**: Create two `ServiceConnection` classes. One responsible for AIDL, one for the messenger.

**Best fix (IMO)**: Decide for one technique at a time. Your solution feels like driving to work (alone) with two cars at the same time.

Comment: Now I understand, but what did you mean: Another fix: Create to ServiceConnection classes. One responsible for AIDL, one for the messenger.

Comment: I like to drive two cars at the same time :D. You should try it.